# jqGrid with JSON showing up empty

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm trying to load a jqGrid from json data made via a REST call. But my grid is just a blank rectangle on the page. Here is my code:

```
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#panel-users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel-clients">Clients</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="panel-users">
        <table id="list"></table> 
        <div id="pager"></div> 
    </div>
    <div id="panel-clients">

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'http://192.168.20.155:3000/admin/rest/users',
    dataType: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Id','Username', 'Minutes','Status','Message','Notes','Troublemaker'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'id', index:'id', width:11}, 
      {name:'username', index:'username', width:90}, 
      {name:'minutes', index:'minutes', width:3, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'status', index:'status', width:80, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'message', index:'message', width:80, align:'right', sortable:false}, 
      {name:'note', index:'note', width:150, sortable:false},
      {name:"troublemaker", index:'troublemaker', width:1}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'username',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'My test grid',
    jsonReader : {
    root: "rows",
    page: "page",
    total: "total",
    records: "records",
    repeatitems: true,
    cell: "cell",
    id: "id",
        userdata: "userdata"
    }
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

And here is the JSON data that the url returns:

> {"page":0,"records":"3","total":1,"rows":[{"cell":["1","admin","30","enabled",null,null,"0"]},{"cell":["2","test1","30","enabled",null,null,"0"]},{"cell":["3","test2","30","enabled",null,null,"0"]}]}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So no part of the grid is showing up?

Have you made sure to include both the grid.locale-en.js file (assuming this is in English) and the jquery.jqGrid.min.js files?  That would be my first guess, missing the grid.locale-en.js file.

Comment: It looks good to me. Here it is for your inspection:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.20.155:3000/static/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.20.155:3000/static/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>

All the links work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I simply had to include `grid.locale-en.js` *before* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.